# How do I prevent script from crashing as a result of failed proc?

Tags: raku

I've got this:

```
try { run 'tar', '-zxvf', $path.Str, "$dir/META6.json", :err }
```

Despite being in a `try{}` block, this line is still causing my script to crash:

```
The spawned command 'tar' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1, signal: 0)
  in block  at ./all-versions.raku line 27
  in block  at ./all-versions.raku line 16
  in block <unit> at ./all-versions.raku line 13
```

Why isn't the `try{}` block allowing the script to continue and how can I get it to continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `run` didn't fail (yet).  `run` returns a [`Proc`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Proc) object.  And that by itself doesn't throw (yet).

`try` just returns that `Proc` object.  As soon as the returned value is used however (for instance, by having it sunk), *then* it will throw.

Compare (with immediate sinking):

```
$ raku -e 'run "foo"'
The spawned command 'foo' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1, signal: 0)
```

with:

```
$ raku -e 'my $a = run "foo"; say "ran, going to sink"; $a.sink'
ran, going to sink
The spawned command 'foo' exited unsuccessfully (exit code: 1, signal: 0)
```

Now, what causes the usage of the `Proc` object in your code, is unclear.  You'd have to show more code.

A way to check for success, is to check the [`exit-code`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Proc#method_exitcode):

```
$ raku -e 'my $a = run "foo"; say "failed" if $a.exitcode > 0'
failed

$ raku -e 'my $a = run "echo"; say "failed" if $a.exitcode > 0'
```

Or alternately, use Jonathan's solution:

```
$ raku -e 'try sink run "foo"'
```

Comment: Maybe worth suggesting `try sink run '...'`, which is the "I don't care why it fails, just ignore it" solution that was probably originally wanted.